# Adding Textarea as filter in ui listing

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent, filter, listing

I want to add filtering for a ui listing

```
<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
```

Using this i am able to add filter but its a textbox. I want it to be a textarea any solution on this.

Comment: Why you want to added textarea into the filter?

Comment: Where do you want to add textarea? product grid or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Magneto2 default not provide the `textarea` as filter type.

You can check this directory so you get idea how many type of filter is currently available into the magento ui grid.

```
MagentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Filters/Type
```

According to my suggestion, you are use text field as filter instead of textarea, because they are allows you to add those data and filter it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to make textarea as a filter type.

> In magento, currently text, select, dateRange and textRange
>   types of filters are available only.